How to remember the Caratheodory criterion?
Caratheodory famously described how to construct a measure from an outer measure. Key to this is the Caratheodory criterion, which says a set $A$ should be measurable if, for every $E,$ we have
$$\mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \cap A^c).$$
However, I frequently have trouble remembering if the condition is "$A$ is measurable if the above is true for every $E,$" or if the condition is "$E$ is measurable if the above is true for every $A.$" Is there some easy way to remember which is which? It is slightly hard for me to think about since every set I can imagine is measurable!

Your first statement is correct. I think a way to remember is to think that you are trying to look at a set's ($A$ here) measurability using $E$. You think of $E$ as a cookie cutter and cut into your space. Some part falls inside $A$, the rest outside $A$, that is in $A^c$. The total size of $E$ is the sum of the sizes of the cuts. If all cookie cutters satisfy this, then your set is measurable.

Intuitively, caratheodory theorem is equivalent to your outer and inner measures agreeing. In fact if your measure space is finite, then this statement is equivalent to measurability.

A simple example of a measure in which not every set is measurable is the cocountable measure on any uncountable set. You may find that helpful in understanding the Caratheodory criterion.

Caratheodory’s condition is that a set is measurable if and only if it and its complement cut every subset into pieces for which additivity holds. The intuitive explanation HackR gives for this definition in the comments seems correct to me.
On Rob Arthan raising the question of counting measure on an uncountable space having nonmeasurable sets in the comments: The existence of nonmeasurable set for Lebesgue measure requires the axiom of choice. It has been shown that there are models of mathematics for which every set is Lebesgue measurable. These models put restrictions on the axiom of choice.

The condition you state in your original post is equivalent to the following condition for measurability of $A$:

If we have an outer measure $\mu^*$, we say that a set $A \subset X$ is $\mu^*$-measurable if and only if$$\mu^*(Y) = \mu^*(Y \cap A) + \mu^*(Y \setminus A)$$for all $Y \subset X$.

As you say, this is a condition for measurability of $A$.  To keep straight what set is said to be measurable, it might be worth focusing on the condition for Lebesgue measurability of $S \subset I$: $$m(S) = m^*(S) = m_*(S),$$where $$m^*(S) = \text{inf}\left\{\sum_{k \ge 0} \ell(J_k) : S \subset \bigcup_{k \ge 0} J_k\right\}\,(J_k\,\text{intervals}), \quad m_*(S) = \ell(I) - m^*(I \setminus S).$$A related result to consider is:

Suppose we are given an algebra $\mathbf{A}$ of subsets of $X$ and a premeasure $\mu_0$ on $\mathbf{A}$, with associated outer measure $\mu^*$. Assume $Z \subset X$ is $\mu^*$-measurable and $\mu^*(Z) < \infty$. Then a set $S \subset Z$ is $\mu^*$-measurable if and only if$$\mu^*(S) + \mu^*(Z \setminus S) = \mu^*(Z).$$

This gives a condition equivalent to measurability of a set $S$, given that $S\subset Z$, $Z$ is measurable, and has finite measure. This latter result may be closer in structure to certain characterizations of measurability than what you said in your original post, and might be easier to keep in mind.

There may not be any better insight than what one gets from the "inner measure vs. outer measure" idea, but probably not worth worrying too much about. Yes, this criterion for measurability is technical and rather unintuitive, and I too always have to think twice to make sure I have the roles of $A$ and $E$ straight.  But this criterion is a technical tool that nobody actually has to use directly very often. Two key places where Caratheodory's theorem gets used: First with extending (pre)measures from algebras to sigma-algebras, and then with proving the Riesz representation theorem that turns linear functionals on spaces of continuous functions into measures.  Once we've got these two results, they're the ones that we actually use all the time, and the methods for proving them fade into the background.
Nonmeasurable sets in "ordinary" geometric situations like $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{R}^n$ are sets that are spread out in an extremely irregular fashion. We can't produce them without invoking the axiom of choice, which means that examples can never be described very concretely. The example of a subset $N$ of $[0,1]$ such that the distance between any two numbers in $N$ is irrational, and which isn't contained in any larger set with this property, is pretty typical.
Any set that anyone will ever meet in practice is measurable. We have to remember that nonmeasurable sets are there so that we don't make stupid mistakes, but they won't reach out and bite us (except in certain very specialized situations).

The idea of Caratheodory’s condition is that a set $A$ is measurable if it is simple enough that it divides every set $E$ (using $A$ and $E$ as in the original post) in a way that the sizes of the two parts of $E$ add to the size of $E$. Of course, the set and the outer measure under consideration can be horribly complex, but the good thing here is that the collection of sets $A$ that divide all sets in a nice way turns out to be a nice collection of sets on which the restriction of the outer measure is in fact a measure (which is the goal of all of this).
It turns out that for many purposes the Borel sets, which form a subcollection of the Caratheodory measurable sets, are a very nice domain on which measures live.

Another way to remember which of the two sets is which: One always wants the whole space to be measurable.  However, in the case of a weird finite outer measure on a set with at least two members  (say when each nonempty subset of the space has outer measure $1$), the whole space would not be measurable if $E$ were the set whose measurability is being tested, since $1$ is not equal to $1+1$.
